# PowerBi - Counting Switch Statements

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following measure:

```
test = SWITCH(TRUE(),
MAX(test[month])>=9&&MAX(test[month])<=12,"fall",
MAX(test[month])>=1&&MAX(test[month])<=3,"winter",
MAX(test[month])>=4&&MAX(test[month])<=6,"spring",
MAX(test[month])>=7&&MAX(test[month])<=8,"summer")
```

Currently it looks at the month number (i.e. "3" for March and outputs "winter", what I'd like however is it to output is a count per season to show the distribution of the seasons in the dataset.

For example my desired output would be

| Month Number | Count of occurrences of each season |
| --- | --- |
| fall | 5 |
| winter | 7 |
| spring | 11 |
| summer | 2 |

I can't have a calculated column here either as I will want to make this measure dynamic later on with the use of a slicer, can someone tell me if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you want to define your categories within the measure. Measures are not dynamic without some filter-context.
Take this for example:

[image]

Notice that the output of the calculation is identical between seasons.
There is no filter context to help the measure discern between the different seasons because these seasons are not defined in the model. (At least, I don't know how to make this work)

Comment: It's a good idea to use var table

Answer (score 0):

Switch returns the first true result. So, if you have values like in your sample, then start with the smallest, then bigger, and the largest at the end.

```
test = 
SWITCH(
     TRUE()
     ,MAX(test[month])<4,"winter" -- test <4 
     ,MAX(test[month])<7,"spring" -- 3< test < 7
     ,MAX(test[month])<9,"summer" -- 6< test < 9 -- Is it ok that you have 2 months in 
     ,"fall"                      -- 8< test      -- summer and 4 in fall?
)
```

If you use `MAX(test[month])<4,"winter"` instead of `MAX(test[month])<=3,"winter"` then you avoid one calculation step and the code will be faster.

Then you need to use the result to find months numbers and get dates from the selected months. Then calculate your table filtered by months dates. If this answer is not enough to solve the case, then give more information about you table, it's columns, and what do you mean by 'Count of occurrences of each season', exactly what does 'occurrences' mean, is it a number of certain rows or some unique values.

Comment: thank you for that nugget of information, in addition to that, is my question solvable?

Comment: I don't see obstacles not to solve the issue